# Is Sanderson's Warbreaker available for free in ePub format?

Tags: cosmere, warbreaker

Brandon Sanderson has released his novel Warbreaker for free on his website.
As far as I can tell, it is available in form of [web articles](https://brandonsanderson.com/warbreaker-introduction/), and downloadable in various formats, [mainly PDF and Word](https://brandonsanderson.com/books/warbreaker/warbreaker/warbreaker-rights-and-downloads/).

I'd like to know if this work is also freely available somewhere in more "modern" and usable formats, in particular ePub.

**EDIT:**
I have to make some clarifications, because, like some users pointed out, a simple search gives *some* results.
I'm interested in a good formatted and properly built ePub, while most of the results that I got from a websearch were not really good-looking (some are also lacking a proper Table of Contents) and seemed more like automated conversions from other formats rather than ePub created *ad hoc*.
I'm not really interested in those because, given the original source files from Sanderson's website, I could have done a raw conversion myself with Calibre.
Furthermore, given that this book was also released commercially, from some other search results I could not easily tell if it was a legitimate version or a pirated one; I'm not interested in those either, I don't really want to steal from an author that has kindly released one of his works for free.

*I should have explicitly stated all of this from the beginning, sorry for having written the question in a hurry.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because, while it isn't an off-topic or opinion-based one, I don't think it's a good fit for our site. It could also have been handled with a a [single search](http://manybooks.net/titles/sandersonbother08Warbreaker.html).

Comment: Voting to re-open this is not a list question, or a recommendation.

Comment: VTRO. While not a great question, we have a handful of similar questions like this, and they don't violate any actual established rule or policy. Worth a DV, perhaps, but not a VTC.

Comment: I'm sorry to have caused trouble, I had consulted the help center and I was under the impression that this kind of question was legitimate; I have also edited my question to make clearer its scope. If this is still on the grey zone and not really fitting on this site, I will understand if it has to be closed.
I also want to say that I don't want others to perform a search on my behalf, I hope that my edit can better explain what I needed. Anyway, thanks to everyone for the feedback.

Comment: @Sekhemty - Shopping questions are fine where there's been a legitimate effort to find the product. I've voted to reopen.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications @Sekhemty.  PDF conversion is notoriously difficult, you probably already know that since you mention doing Calibre yourself, and at a guess nobody has actually invested the time to correct all the formatting issues properly, on their own time.  I haven't run across any myself, but I didn't know about archive.org from tobiasvl's answer, so I guess I'll be checking that out later myself.

Comment: Yes, converting from PDF usually gives a readable text, nothing more. And properly creating an ePub takes time, so before putting my effort into it, I was looking if someone else had already done this. The version from archive.org seems to be a decent one, it appears to be a good basis that only needs some tweaks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's available as ePub many places, like [the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Warbreaker).

The book wasn't released as an ePub by Sanderson himself, but [the license of the book](https://brandonsanderson.com/warbreaker-rights-explanation/) explicitly [allows changing the format](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#when-i-release-my-work-under-a-cc-license-in-one-format-e.g.-.pdf-can-i-restrict-licensees-from-changing-it-to-or-using-it-in-other-formats), so these ePubs are completely legal.

Comment: Thank you, this version seems to be a decent ePub!